# Reading a *.json file in java

Tags: java, json, http

I want to get the json object from the given url which provides a downloadable link for the *.json file.
The *.json file contains one json object in it.
I have tried the following code with each I could read the *.json file as a string but when I convert it into a json object it throws an exception.

```
URL url = new URL(fileurl);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = br.readLine();
while (line != null) 
{
    sb.append(line);
    line = br.readLine();
}
result = sb.toString();
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);`
```

I dont want to use `org.json.simple` library.
is there any other way it could be achieved like using `org.json` lib

Comment: What exception?

Comment: May I ask why you want to reinvent the wheel over using one of the existing, well-developed and tested implementations?

Comment: @Ben from his last sentence I think he doesn't want to use *that specific library*, but he's open to use another one

Comment: @user2340612 ah indeed. That does make more sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    URL obj = new URL(<url>);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());
```

This is using the org.json:json. This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If using `org.json.simple` library is your problem then there are many other libraries available in java

You can try using the Gson Library by google.

From : https://github.com/google/gson

> Gson is a Java library that can be used to convert Java Objects into
>   their JSON representation. It can also be used to convert a JSON
>   string to an equivalent Java object. Gson can work with arbitrary Java
>   objects including pre-existing objects that you do not have
>   source-code of.
>
> There are a few open-source projects that can convert Java objects to
>   JSON. However, most of them require that you place Java annotations in
>   your classes; something that you can not do if you do not have access
>   to the source-code. Most also do not fully support the use of Java
>   Generics. Gson considers both of these as very important design goals.